# Url routing not working in my PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

My .htaccess code 
it still shows the file name in the link(http://localhost/examp/myproj(urlrouting)/signup.php)
But on clicking on signup i want the link to be (http://localhost/examp/myproj(urlrouting)/SignUp)
using xampp

```
RewriteEngine On    
 # Redirect Trailing Slashes...

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^index index.php            

#RewriteRule ^test/([(A-za-z0-9)]+) test.php?test=$1        

RewriteRule ^SignUp signup.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following in your .htaccess file should accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^SignUp/?$    signup.php    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "SignUp"
```